# Hackerrank: Sherlock and Anagrams(Moderate under Strings section)

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

Problem description: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-anagrams

Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong? My algorithm is:

1. Input the string ; str
2. Generate a pattern string from length i=1 to str.length-2
3. Check whether anagram of pattern string exist in str.substring(i+1)

Below are the test cases which are NOT passing :

```
input-string   My OP   Expected OP
ifailuhkqq     2         3
```

My code:

```
public class SherlockandAnagrams
{
    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        generatePairs(sc.next());
        int len = 1;
    }

    public static void generatePairs(String str)
    {
        int len = 1;
        //int i=0;
        while (len < str.length())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i + len <= str.length(); i++)
                findAnagramPairs(str, len, str.substring(i, i + len), i + 1);
            len++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }

    private static void findAnagramPairs(String str, int len, String pattern, int p)
    {
        int i = p;
        while (i + len <= str.length())
        {
            if (checkAnagram(pattern, str.substring(i, i + len)))
            {
                count++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkAnagram(String pattern, String text)
    {
        if (pattern.length() == 1)
        {
            if (pattern.equals(text))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            int j = pattern.length() - 1;
            while (i < pattern.length())
            {
                if (pattern.charAt(i) == text.charAt(j))
                {
                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
                else
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution to the problem would be the following:
An anagramic pair with starting-indices at `(n , m)` and length `l` can only exist, if another pair with length `l - 1` at `(n or n - 1 or n + 1 , m or m - 1 or m - 1)` exists. Thus we can easily reduce efficiency from bruteforce to a more efficient solution.

An example:

```
        A B C B A A B C A
len 1   A       A A     A //all pairs containing A
len 2   A B   B A         //all pairs that match A B or its reverse
len 3   A B C B A         //all pairs that match A B C or its reverse
```

OR

```
        A B C B A A B C A
len 1     B   B     B     //all pairs containing B
len 2     B C B     B C   //all pairs that match B C or its reverse
len 3   A B C B A A B C   //all pairs that match A B C or its reverse
```

The same applies to any other pair of length `l` and it's matching pairs with length `l + 1`. In general, a pair of length `l + 1` only exists, if two pairs `(a , b)` and `(c , d)` of length `l` exists, such that either `a = c - l` and `b = d + l` or `a = c + l` and `b = d - l` exist.

In pseudocode this would look like this:

```
set pairs = listAnagrams(input , 1)

int len = 1
while NOT pairs.isEmpty()
    set next_len

    //generate pairs with length len + 1
    for pair p in pairs
        pair left = pair(p.a - len , p.b + len)
        pair right = pair(p.a + len , p.b - len)

        if pairs.contains(left)
            next_len.add(pair(p.a , left.b)
        if pairs.contains(right)
            next_len.add(pair(left.a , p.b)

    pairs = next_len
    ++len
```