# How can I reduce the complexity of these two methods?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, time-complexity

I have some code like

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
class Solution
{

    // returns true or false based on whether s1 and s2 are 
    // an unordered anagrammatic pair
    // e.g. "aac","cac" --> false
    //      "aac","aca" --> true  
    // Complexity: O(n)
    static bool IsAnagrammaticPair(string s1, string s2)
    {
        if(s1.Length != s2.Length)
            return false;
        int[] counter1 = new int[26],
              counter2 = new int[26];
        for(int i = 0; i < s1.Length; ++i)
        {
            counter1[(int)s1[i] - (int)'a'] += 1;
            counter2[(int)s2[i] - (int)'a'] += 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i)
            if(counter1[i] != counter2[i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    // gets all substrings of s (not including the empty string, 
    // including s itself)
    // Complexity: O(n^2)
    static IEnumerable<string> GetSubstrings(string s)
    {
        return  from i in Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length)
                from j in Enumerable.Range(0, s.Length - i + 1)
                where j >= 1
                select s.Substring(i, j);
    }

    // gets the number of anagrammatical pairs of substrings in s
    // Complexity: O(n^2)
    static int NumAnagrammaticalPairs(string s)
    {
        var substrings = GetSubstrings(s).ToList();
        var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, substrings.Count);
        return (from i in indices
                from j in indices
                where i < j && IsAnagrammaticPair(substrings[i], substrings[j])
                select 1).Count();
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int T = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for(int t = 0; t < T; ++t)
        {
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(NumAnagrammaticalPairs(line));
        }
    }
}
```

which is not meeting the performance benchmarks of the problem. The two helper methods I have

```
GetSubstrings
```

and

```
NumAnagrammaticalPairs
```

I know are `O(n^2)` as I mentioned in the comments, however I don't see how I can reduce the number of operations involved in retrieving the answer. Any ideas?

Comment: `NumAnagrammaticalPairs` calls `IsAnagrammaticPair`, so that makes the former O(n^3)

Comment: I dont think you can reduce the complexity of the `GetSubstrings` & `NumAnagrammaticalPairs`. You may do some improvements on them, like using regular 2 nested for statements instead of using Linq & enumerables. Not sure if that is good enough

Comment: Or you may discard both methods, an approach it with Dynamic Programming. See https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/

Comment: Spoiler alert: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925148/hackerrank-sherlock-and-anagramsmoderate-under-strings-section

Comment: Is the question you are trying to solve actually just calculating the cardinality of a set? If so, enumerating the set is probably not part of an efficient solution.

Comment: Looking at the problem parameters, I'd guess that an O(n^2) solution is fine, but your O(n^4) solution is a bit much. With O(n^2), you can still generate every substring, but you can't then pair them with themselves and test every pair.

Comment: Questions about improving *working* code belong on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to check for anagarmatic pair. Not sure about performance though.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string x="aac";
        string y ="caa";

      List<char> lstX = x.ToCharArray().OrderBy(m=>m).ToList<char>();
      List<char> lstY =y.ToCharArray().OrderBy(m=>m).ToList<char>();


        Console.WriteLine(IsAnagramaticPair(x,y));
    }

    public static bool IsAnagramaticPair(string x ,string y)
    {
        List<char> lstX = x.ToCharArray().OrderBy(m=>m).ToList<char>();
        List<char> lstY =y.ToCharArray().OrderBy(m=>m).ToList<char>();

        return lstX.SequenceEqual(lstY);

    }
}
```

Comment: You just provided a O(n log n) for what the OP solved with O(n).

Comment: but to be fair, the question does not states correctly that OP wanted to reduce big O "algorithm complexity" instead of cyclomatic complexity, so you dont deserve a downvote... }

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities that come to mind. First, sort both strings and compare the results:

```
static bool IsAnagrammaticPair(string s1, string s2)
{
    var srt1 = s1.OrderBy(c => c);
    var srt2 = s2.OrderBy(c => c);
    return s1.SequenceEqual(s2);
}
```

If m and n are the lengths of the strings, then that is O(n log n + m log m).

Another possibility is to make a histogram of characters from one string, and then compare the characters and associated counts from the other string. The strings have to be the same length for that to work, though:

```
static bool IsAnagrammaticPair(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1.Length != s2.Length) return false;

    var l1 = s1.ToLookup(c => c);
    return s2.GroupBy(c => c).All(g => l1.Contains(g.Key) && l1[g.Key].Count() == g.Count());
}
```

That's O(n) for the first part, with O(n) extra space. And O(m) for the second part.

Answer (score 0):

You can take subsets of the substrings so that each subset is composed of strings having the same length.

After that you can or using a sort O(n log n) to make a direct comparison between the strings.

And also use the sort to arrange each subset in the good order (so no ixj comparisons).

```
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        int T = Int32.Parse( Console.ReadLine() );
        for ( int t = 0 ; t < T ; ++t )
        {
            string line = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine( NumAnagrammaticalPairs( line ) );
        }
    }

    static int NumAnagrammaticalPairs( string s )
    {
        int sum = 0;
        foreach ( var substrings in GetSubstringsByLength( s ) )
        {
            // Count for each string how many others are identical
            int toSum = 0;
            for ( int i = 1 ; i < substrings.Count ; i++ )
                if ( substrings[i - 1] == substrings[i] )
                {
                    toSum++;
                    sum += toSum;
                }
                else
                {
                    toSum = 0;
                }
        }

        return sum;
    }

    static IEnumerable<List<string>> GetSubstringsByLength( string s )
    {
        for ( int length = 1 ; length < s.Length ; length++ )
            yield return GetSubstringsOfLength( s, length );
    }

    static List<string> GetSubstringsOfLength( string s, int length )
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        for ( int i = 0 ; i <= s.Length - length ; i++ )
        {
            var substring = s.Substring( i, length );
            result.Add( new string( substring.OrderBy( c => c ).ToArray<char>() ) );
        }

        result.Sort();

        return result;
    }
```